# Invalid type argument of '*' (have 'double') C

Tags: c, cygwin

I'm trying to learn C, and in my recent code came across a compile error that I do not understand. I don't really understand what the error means, so I therefor have trouble fixing the problem. I've done extensive googling, but didn't understand the explanations that i came across.

Can someone clarify?

The error:

[image: cygwin compilartion output]

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "plant.h"

double watercredit = 0.0;
int needwater = 200;
double wateredamount = 0.0;

int main()
{
    watercredit=215.00;

    while(watercredit > 0.0)
    {
        watercredit--;
        if(watercredit < needwater)
        {
            printf("You need to water the plant!\n");
            printf("enter amount of water:\n");
            scanf("%lf", wateredamount);
            watered(&wateredamount);
            //watercredit = watercredit + wateredamount;
            wateredamount = 0;
        }
        if(watercredit == 0)
        {
            printf("You plant died!");
            return 0;
        }

        printf("Watercredit: %lf\n", watercredit);
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}

//takes the amount of water added and increases credit
void watered(double* amount)
{
    *watercredit = *watercredit + amount;
}
```

Plant.h:

```
void watered(double* amount);
```

Comment: Unrelated to the error, but `scanf("%lf", wateredamount);` should be `scanf("%lf", &wateredamount);`. Also, note that there is no need need to pass `wateredamount` by reference to the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dereferencing the wrong variable.

If you look at your function watered then `amount` is of the type `double*`, i.e. a pointer to a double. However, `watercredit` is a global variable of type `double`. You cannot use the `*` operator on a double since that is not a pointer.

This function should work:

```c
//takes the amount of water added and increases credit
void watered(double* amount)
{
    watercredit = watercredit + *amount;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `amount` as a pointer to `watered`, not `watercredit`, which is a `double` (it is also a global variable so not a good idea).

The general idea of c declarations is that they show you how it's expected to be used, so that

```
double wateredamount = 0.0;
```

is expected to be used in expressions like `a = wateredamount + 1` or `wateredamount = 5`. Whereas

```
void watered(double* amount)
```

indicates you are expecting to see expressions like

```
 thing = *amount
```

Which are the opposite to what your code is actually doing